# How can i store results from a Row to a string object using the XDevAPI

Tags: c++, mysql

I am using mysql connector/C++ 8.16, XDevAPI and I want to store data which I get from each row in the table into a string, but I can't. I get different errors.

The following code works :

```
mysqlx::RowResult rows = mySession.sql("SELECT * FROM testtable").execute();

for (mysqlx::Row row : rows)
{           
    std::cout << row[0] << std::endl;
}
```

but if I want to store `row[0]` into a string, it's not working.

```
mysqlx::string s = row[0];//error, Value cannot be converted to string
```

I have already tried to cast it into a `mysqlx::string` but it's not working, I get the error :

> "Value cannot be converted to string".

I managed to do it with `stringstream` but it's not really what I want.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the reference  in detail i found that you can do something like :

```
mysqlx::string s = row[0].get<mysqlx::string>();
int val = row[1].get<int>();
```

and so on to convert the data.

Comment: Looks like in the Value class in document.h it says "using string = mysqlx::string;" so I guess that allows you to then use mysqlx::strings as std::strings. (?)